# AsyncTask give lag for the task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My project is to get data from database to my listview in my project. It get data but when I close and run the application more than one time it gives lag(the data is hidden but when I scroll the list view it show out)

my code is

```
    private class SendfeedbackJob extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String page="";

    protected String doInBackground(String...params) {
        // do above Server call here
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
        "http://192.168.43.16/marche/category_display.php");    
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
        response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();
         page = sb.toString();



                     String [] s= page.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                     for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
                         Cat_Name[i]=s[i];
                     }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
        in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        }

        return page;

            }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
        //process message
        Log.d("MyAsyncTask", "Received result: " + message);
    }


}
```

and the on the oncreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SendfeedbackJob pro=new SendfeedbackJob();
    pro.execute();
 }
```

Comment: how do you know that Cats is ready to be displayed? where do you set your adapter or call notifydatasetchanged. add those codes and specify the place you do that.

Answer (score 0):

The data is hidden. because, obviously you are not waiting until `doInBackground` to finish processing before you refresh the adapter (`Cats` array is still empty). when you scroll down few seconds later the list view will ask the adapter for the data in the bottom cells and scrolling up before the list view asks for the top cells and they just get displayed.

> You must set your adapter or calling notifyDataSetChanged in
>   `onPostExecute` method.

Answer (score 0):

- Call `notifydatasetchanged` method in the UI thread after fetching all the data
- While fetching the data show progress bar to avoid some bad UI experience if the process takes a lot of time